# Call to undefined method PDO::execute()

Tags: php, pdo

i'm trying to code a page login but i was stopper at this error

pliz tell me the wrong thing here

```
<?php
@session_start();
include("../../connexion/connexion.php");
class login_class {
        public $user;
        public $password;
        public $connexion;
    public function check_login() {
        try {
            $cn = new class_connect();
            $this->connexion = $cn->connect(null);
            $result = $this->connexion->execute("select * from user where username='$this->user' and password='$this->password'");

                        $data = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);


            if (!empty($data[0]->id_user)) {
                return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        }catch(PDOException $ex) {  
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
    public function __construct($user) {
        if($user){
            $this->user = $user["username"];
            $this->password = $user["password"];
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: `execute()` is a method of `PDOStatement` not `PDO`. The way you are using PDO here is a bit confused.

Comment: pliz can u give me the right syntax

Comment: You're probably thinking of `PDO::exec()` although that is not appropriate for your query either. You should use `PDO::query()` when doing a `SELECT` statement. Additionally, you have SQL injection issues with your code. You should take the time to read about PDO's prepared statements.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`->execute()` is for prepared statements. e.g.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('some query here');
$stmt->execute();
```

You're trying to execute a query directly on the main DB object. For PDO, that means

```
 $dbh->exec('query goes here');
```

You really should look into prepared statements. You're vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) as is, and since you're using PDO to begin with, it's basically unforgivable to NOT be writing safe queries.

Comment: +1 small typo though, I assume you mean "`->execute()` is for prepared statements"?