# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DB::execute()

Tags: php, pdo

I am using [indieteq-php-my-sql-pdo-database-class](https://github.com/wickyaswal/indieteq-php-my-sql-pdo-database-class) I found on GitHub

I have created a little page to try and display some database information as seen below, however I receive the error below my test page script below;

**My Test Page**

```
<?php

require("Db.class.php");
$db = new Db();
$db->query("SELECT * FROM faction_territories");

if ($db->execute()) {
    while ($row = $db->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$row['territory_id'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['density'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['sector'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['size'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['respect'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['faction_name'].'</td>
        </tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}

?>
```

**Error**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DB::execute() in
>   /var/www/.../index.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/.../index.php on line 7

### Questions

As you'll be able to tell, I'm somewhat new to PHP & PDO. Some nice pointers to where I am going wrong would be nice with any example code please.

Comment: But there is really no `execute()` method in `Db` class. I think it's clear

Comment: @DanMiller How would I then display my data please? Do I need to add an `execute()` method or?

Comment: See [sources](https://github.com/wickyaswal/indieteq-php-my-sql-pdo-database-class/blob/master/Db.class.php#L177) It returns `fetchAll()` so you have result as array.

Comment: @DanMiller So `$db` becomes an array? I get the following error if I try to echo `$db` - `Object of class DB could not be converted to string`

Comment: No, why `$db`. `$resultSetArrayWhichYouCanIterate = $db->query("SELECT * FROM faction_territories");`

Comment: There are lots of examples on the Github page. Did you bother reading it?

Comment: Thank you, you helped to get this working. A little answer with what you have said and I'll accept, thanks @DanMiller

Comment: No problem. It doesn't matter, there is already correct answer given. You can accept the existing one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to undefined method PDO::execute()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23371118/call-to-undefined-method-pdoexecute)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $db->query already execute the query. You just need to iterate over the result.

See here: https://github.com/wickyaswal/indieteq-php-my-sql-pdo-database-class/blob/master/Db.class.php#L189