# php mysqli form - fill inputs from select drop-down update

Tags: php, forms, mysqli, onchange

I have a php web page that I can choose from a drop-down select field and it fills in that field as it should, I am having problems with it also filling in some input fields.  I have spent a few days trying all sorts of different solutions found here and elsewhere on google, but few where a mysqli filled drop-down select field is used to fill other input fields. I can get it working where it fills a table, but I need to allow the user to modify the filled in data, so I am using an input field.

TheCDC3.php file:

```
   <?php
   include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
   ?>

   <?php
    $b = intval($_GET['b']);

    $sql="SELECT * FROM Batches WHERE BatchNum = '".$b."'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    }
    ?>
```

The main php file:

```
<?php include_once 'includes/db_connect.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>CDC Wash Run Entry</title>
  <script>
  function showBatch(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtMessage").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } 
    else { 
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtMessage").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","CDC3.php?b="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="WashForm" name="washform" method="POST">
<h1>CDC Wash Run Entry</h2>
<label for="DateTimeCode">DateTimeCode</label>
 <input name="DateTimeCode" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>" required><br>
<label for="BatchNum">BatchNum</label>

    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT BatchNum, BatchName, SourceProduct, SourceIngredient FROM Batches ORDER by BatchNum DESC";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    echo "<select name='BatchNum' id='BatchNum' onchange='showBatch(this.value)'>";
    echo "<option value=''> Select BatchNum        </option>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['BatchNum'] . "'>" . $row['BatchNum'] .' - '. $row['BatchName'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select><br><br>";
    echo "<label for='BatchName'>Batch Name</label>";
    echo " <input name='BatchName' value='".$row['BatchName']."'><br>";
    echo "<label for='SourceProduct'>Source Product</label>";
    echo " <input name='SourceProduct' value='".$row['SourceProduct']."'><br>";
    echo "<label for='SourceIngredient'>Source Ingredient</label>";
    echo "<input name='SourceIngredient' value='".$row['SourceIngredient']."'><br>";
    ?>


</form>        
</body>
</html>
```

---

The working, modified code, sorry for the wall of code, but it works

---

The database/includes/psl-configPDO.php file

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "DBadmin";
$password = "xxxxxxxx"; 
$dbname = "CDCtest";
?>
```

---

The database/includes/db_connect_PDO.php file (This works from command line)

```
<?php
require_once('psl-configPDO.php');
try{
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$servername.';dbname='.$dbname,$username,$password);
                    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    die(json_encode(array('outcome' => true)));
}
catch(PDOException $ex){
    die(json_encode(array('outcome' => false, 
                          'message' => 'Unable to connect to '.$servername.':'.$dbname.' with '.$username)));
}
$dbh = null;
?>
```

---

The database/includes/jquery.min.js is a wget of  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js

---

The database/CDC_Ajax_PDO.php file

```
?>
<?php
require_once('includes/psl-configPDO.php');
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$servername.';dbname='.$dbname,$username,$password);
$sth = $db->prepare('SELECT BatchName, SourceProduct, SourceIngredient FROM Batches WHERE BatchNum =:BatchNum');
$sth->bindParam(':BatchNum', $_POST['BatchNum'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
$data = new stdClass;
$status = 'failed';
if ($row = $sth->fetchObject() ) {
    $data = $row;
    $status = 'success';
    }
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode([
    'status' => $status,
    'data' => $data
    ]);
?>
```

---

the database/CDC_WashFormPDO.php file

```
<?php
require_once('includes/psl-configPDO.php');
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$servername.';dbname='.$dbname,$username,$password);
$db = $pdo->prepare("SELECT BatchNum, BatchName FROM Batches ORDER by BatchNum DESC");
$db->execute();
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html class="supernova"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta property="og:title" content="CDC Wash Run Entry" >
<meta property="og:description" content="Please click submit to complete this form.">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
<head>
 <title>CDC Wash Run Entry</title>
 <script src = includes/jquery.min.js></script>
</head>
<body>
<form class="jotform-form" accept-charset="utf-8" id="WashForm" name="washform" method="POST">
<div class="form-all">
  <ul class="form-section page-section">
    <li id="cid_1" class="form-input-wide" data-type="control_head">
      <div class="form-header-group ">
        <div class="header-text httal htvam">
          <h1>CDC Wash Run Entry</h2>
          <label class="form-label form-label-top form-label-auto">Logged in as: <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']); ?> </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="form-line" data-type="control_textbox">
        <label class="form-label form-label-top form-label-auto" for="DateTimeCode">DateTimeCode</label>
        <div class="form-input-wide">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" size="20" name="DateTimeCode" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>" required>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="form-line" data-type="control_dropdown">
        <label class="form-label form-label-top form-label-auto" for="choose-batch">Choose a Batch</label>
        <div class="form-input-wide">



        <select class='form-dropdown' id='choose-batch'>
          <?php while($row = $db->fetchObject()): ?>
// show both name and number in drop-down
        <option value="<?= $row->BatchNum ?>" ><?= $row->BatchNum." - ".$row->BatchName ?></option>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
          </select>



       </div>
    </li>
    <li class="form-line" data-type="control_textbox">
        <label class="form-label form-label-top form-label-auto" for="BatchName">Batch Name</label>
        <div class="form-input-wide">

          <input type='text' class='form-control' size='20' id="BatchName" name="BatchName" value="<?php echo $row['BatchName'];?>" />

      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="form-line" data-type="control_textbox">
        <label class="form-label form-label-top form-label-auto" for="SourceProduct">Source Product</label>
        <div class="form-input-wide">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" size="20" id="SourceProduct" name="SourceProduct" value="" required>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="form-line" data-type="control_textbox">
        <label class="form-label form-label-top form-label-auto" for="SourceIngredient">Source Ingredient</label>
        <div class="form-input-wide">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" size="20" id="SourceIngredient" name="SourceIngredient" value="" required>
        </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
    <ul class="form-section page-section" >
    <li class="form-line" data-type="control_text" >
      <div class="buttonrow">
        <div class="col-1 form-buttons-wrapper">
            <button type="submit" class="form-submit-button" id="submit_form" name="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      <div class="col-1 form-buttons-wrapper">
         <a href="CDChome.php" >
           <button type="button" class="form-submit-button" >
             Home
           </button>
         </a>
       </div>
       <div class="col-1 form-buttons-wrapper">
          <a href="includes/logout.php">
            <button type="button" class="form-submit-button" >
              Logout
            </button>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</form>        

  <script>
    // monitor for changes in drop-down
    $(document).ready(function() {  // technically not necessary if script is at the bottom, but I do it out of habit
      $('#choose-batch').on('change', function() {
        retrieveItem( $(this).val() );
      })
    });
    // send batchNum via ajax
    function retrieveItem(BatchNumber) {
      $.post(
        "CDC_Ajax_PDO.php",               // where to send data
        {BatchNum: BatchNumber},  // parameters to send {varname: value}
        function(result) {        // what to do with results
          if(result.status=='success') {
            populateForm(result.data);
          } else {
            alert ('oops, failed');
          }
        }
      );
    }
    // put results into page
    function populateForm(data) {
      $('#BatchName').val(data.BatchName);
      $('#SourceProduct').val(data.SourceProduct);
      $('#SourceIngredient').val(data.SourceIngredient);
    }
  </script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you have a follow up question please post it as a new question rather than editing it into this one where it won't get seen.

Comment: I do not have a follow-up question, I was posting my status of the progress in working towards the solution, which we are close to.

Comment: It works now, big thanks to @Tim-Morton

Comment: Please don't add the working code into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're just getting started, here are a few concepts that will make the journey much more pleasant

- It is **essential** that you learn how to use prepared statements instead of putting the variables in the query.  Even though `intval()` in this case should be safe, you just don't want to be in the habit of writing queries that way.  IMHO PDO is *much* better to learn and work with than mysqli.
- Using a javascript library such as JQuery will make ajax and client-side scripting ***much*** easier, and is cross-browser compatible.
- When doing ajax, try to always pass data as json-encoded strings.  Your ajax reply is data, not presentation.
- for non-mvc scripts, try to have all php in the top (initialization, working with user input/redirection, and business logic), and only then html (with php only for looping and data substitution) at the bottom.

With that being said, your CDC3.php script would look something like this (Best practice would be to move DB connection object to its own file, so you Don't Repeat Yourself)

```
<?php

// connection example, see http://https://phpdelusions.net/pdo
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
try {
     $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}


$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT BatchNum, BatchName, SourceProduct, SourceIngredient FROM Batches WHERE BatchNum = ?');
$stmt->execute($_POST['batchNum']);

// initialize $data and $status, in case there are no results
$data = array();
$status = 'failed';
if ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $data = $row;
    $status = 'success';
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode([
    'status' => $status,
    'data' => $data
    ]);
```

This returns data that your client side javascript can receive as data that it can immediately manipulate or insert into dom elements.

Your view would look something like this (I'm not sure what you're doing in your example, so this will select a batch to show):

```
<?php

// connection example, see http://https://phpdelusions.net/pdo
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
try {
     $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("select BatchNum, BatchName from Batches");
$stmt->execute();

// if you were using regular submits back to the same page, you would deal with them here.

?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>jQuery CDN</title>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>CDC Wash Run Entry</h1>
    <div>Batch will be loaded by ajax and displayed in the form below:</div>
    <label for="choose-batch">Choose a Batch</label>
    <select id='choose-batch'>
    <?php foreach($stmt as $row): ?>
        <option value="<?= $row['BatchNum'] ?>" ><?= $row['BatchName'] ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    </select>

    <form id="batch-form">
      <div>
        <label for='batch-name'>Batch Name</label>
        <input id="batch-name" name='BatchName' value="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for='SourceProduct'>Source Product</label>
        <input id="source-product" name='SourceProduct' value="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for='SourceIngredient'>Source Ingredient</label>
        <input id="source-ingredient" name='SourceIngredient' value="">
      </div>
    </form>



  <script>

    // monitor for changes in drop-down
    $(document).ready(function() {  // technically not necessary if script is at the bottom, but I do it out of habit

      $('#choose-batch').on('change', function() {
        retrieveIngredient( $(this).val() );
      })
    });

    // send batchNum via ajax
    function retrieveIngredient(batchNumber) {

      $.post(
        "CDC3.php",               // where to send data
        {batchNum: batchNumber},  // parameters to send {varname: value}
        function(result) {        // what to do with results
          if(result.message=='success') {
            populateForm(result.data);
          } else {
            alert ('oops, failed');
          }
        }
      );
    }

    // put results into page
    function populateForm(data) {
      $('#batch-name').val(data.BatchName);
      $('#source-product').val(data.SourceProduct);
      $('#source-ingredient').val(data.SourceIngredient);
    }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note: this is intended to show concepts, and is not a cut and paste example. It's off the top of my head and might have glaring errors...

Comment: This will be used where access to the internet will not be possible, so linking to googleapis.com won't work...  and I really prefer not to change all my programming to PDO...  But thanks!

Comment: I am trying to glean some useful tips from your code example, but you changed so much I cannot follow what you are doing, I will try to study what you did more in depth, and again, I appreciate the effort.

Comment: You can download jquery, I just used the cdn for simplicity.  The database code is to show an example of prepared statements; mysqli supports prepared statements (hence improved), but pdo puts it into a much more useable interface. Personally, I had to support several different connection types at my job, so the first thing I did was write an object for each type so that my scripts don’t have to mess with all the idiosyncrasies...

Comment: I think there are too many changes in the code and spots where someone not intimately familiar with PDO will fall in a hole... I have spent 12 hours trying to integrate this into my page, half of that is studying beginner PDO code examples, and I can't even get the page to load...  I appreciate your help, but this is very frustrating...

Comment: I probably introduced too many things at once.  And you may have missed that this example is ***like** PDO, but it isn't, it's just pseudo code (`Database` is a custom object that simplifies DB access for me)  I'll edit my answer to try to make it closer to what you're used to.

Comment: OK, hopefully this works a little better for you.  The website mentioned above - https://phpdelusions.net/pdo - is a great resource.

Comment: I spent 12 hours today changing the format, learning 'like' PDO from the beginning...  I just got it done, and stuck at the $db->execute(); command in the main form, should there be anything passed in that?  "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute() in /var/www/html/database/CDC_WashFormPDO.php:5"

Comment: I have posted my latest changes, they do not cover your changes, I was working on the previous recommendations and would be happy to get a critique of what I did. It took 12+ hours, but I got the page working  and verified I am pulling database info properly, (basically back to where it was with my mysqli procedural style), it does not fill the input fields, I appreciate the help so far...

Comment: I see the reason the fields are not filling in. Before I just blurt it out, though, let me point you to a tool that is indispensable when working with ajax:  the developer console.  In chrome, right click on the page, and choose "inspect".  This gives you several tabs, one of them being "network".  This will let you see the information flowing to and from the browser.  If you look at the ajax response, you'll see the error:  it's sending back html instead of json data.

Comment: The error is in `database/CDC_Ajax_PDO.php`.  This is an example of why output comes **last**.   1)  By  issuing `?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>`, your header will not work, because there cannot be ***any*** output before the header.  2) Since this is json data, there should be NO html.  Just the json-encoded string.

Comment: Oh, one other thing:  `$(‘#batch-name’)` refers to the element having `id=“batch-name”`. Your latest code has omitted the id attribute on inputs, so function `populateForm()` has no idea where to put the data.

Comment: OK, i think I understand why the file should not have html in it...  I found batchName mis-matching BatchName, and fixed that, and I did find two instances where the id was missing, id="SourceIngredient" and id="SourceProduct", and I am using the console (network does not seem to show much) and see "POST http://192.168.2.66/database/CDC_Ajax_PDO.php 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: question, do the "id=" statements for the three  <input> fields I want to fill need to have the id of the database field they will get, or do all three need the same the id of the drop-down?

Comment: It looks like the failure is at the `$db->execute($_POST['BatchNum']);` line, I am getting "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute() in /var/www/html/database/CDC_Ajax_PDO.php:6
" when run it from the command line...  if I try to change it to `$BatchNum = $_POST['BatchNum'];
$db->bindParam(1, $BatchNum, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$db->execute();`  it fails at the bindParam

Comment: The `id=""` statements are strictly for the benefit of JQuery.  They are agnostic about any database activity.  Regarding the fatal error, You shouldn't ever need `bindParam()`; just put the data into `execute()`.  `bindParam()` will just confuse the heck out of you, because it binds a variable, not a value.  The error is saying that you have something wrong with how you're using the PDO object you created.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23371118/call-to-undefined-method-pdoexecute

Comment: I have progress, the CDC_Ajax_PDO.php file needed to have the prepare() be a different string...   now getting the 'oops' popup after selecting, but making progress

Comment: stupid me, I goofed on the first example.  `$stmt = $pdo->prepare(...)` `$pdo->execute(...)` is wrong.  It should be `$stmt->execute()`.  The error you're getting is because `execute()` is a method of `PDOStatement` not `PDO`

Comment: you are amazing, I am learning, and you gave the caveat of such things being possible...,  now getting the following result viewed in the console from the CDC_Ajax_PDO.php: `{"status":"success","data":{"BatchName":"TBBC Whiskey","SourceProduct":"Malt Wort","SourceIngredient":"Malted Barley"}}`  but the "function(result) is failing...   thinking that `if(result.message=='success') ` needs to be something like `if(result.message.status=='success') ` or `if(result.status=='success')`

Comment: BINGO - `if(result.status=='success') `   AND IT WORKS!!!!    edit, I had a static variable assignment, it stopped working when that was removed(it always gave the same info, no matter what was selected) I get status=failed, but I can find and fix that, and will update the code to reflect the working version

Comment: Whew!  Way to go!